# Filtering a view on more than one tag at once

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

I have a job view which I can filter on a specific sector or a specific region.

[image]

However, my filtering so far only works one at a time. I would like to be able to specify: show all jobs in sector AND region. My link output is like this at the moment: jobsview/[name] (with the name of the term). I guess it would have to be something like jobsview/[clickedsector]/[clickedregion], but I don't know how to do this

Can anyone help me out please?

EDIT:

My filter on pageview:
[image]

This is what my link output looks like, ive done the same thing for both sector and region:

[image]

So what I want is being able to filter on both of them at the same time

Comment: Which part of the problem do you need help with? Generating the links or configuring the view? If it's the former, we'll need a lot more information about how they are currently generated.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment, I've updated my question with more information, could you have a look at it please?

Comment: First thing - you'll need two contextual filters. Instead of setting two vocabularies on one filter, set sector on the first and region on the second. That'll mean the view accepts arguments as you seem to want. If you can't work out how to code the output links let me know.

Comment: Okay so I've set up a second contextual filter for Region (which doesn't work though it displays page could not be found), how do I format my output links? Do I have to add any relationships?

Comment: Your output links should be rewritten as basepath/[fieldname1]/[fieldname2] where [fieldname1] is the token for the sector field and [fieldname2] the one for the region. Both these fields will need to appear ahead of the link field in the list in order for you to be able to use them as tokens.

Comment: Hi, I tried that already however when I click a region, say usa, my link output becomes basepath/finance/usa

This is because I have a job that has its region on usa and its sector on finance. I would like to be able to filter only on one argument, as well as on 2. I hope I make sense

Comment: You can do that, you just need to set the second contextual filter so it shows all results when the value is not present.